# Why doesn't `last` let me quit a foreach loop?

Tags: perl, counting, word-count

I want to calculate the number of sentences that contain a word. I have 2 files, one contains sentences and the other contains words, so for each word I would count the number of sentences containing this word.

This is my code:

```
use strict;
use autodie;
use autodie;

open my $fh_resultat, ">:utf8", 'out';
use constant CORPUS_MOT => 'test';
use constant CORPUS_Phrases => 'phrases';
my @tab_MOT_CORPUS = do {
    open my $fh1, "<:utf8", CORPUS_MOT;
    map { split } <$fh1>;

};

my @tab_phrase_CORPUS = do {
    open my $fh2, "<:utf8", CORPUS_Phrases;
    map { split } <$fh2>;

};

foreach my $mot (@tab_MOT_CORPUS) {

    my $nb_phrase = 0;

    foreach my $ph (@tab_phrase_CORPUS) {

        my @tab = split(/ /, $ph);

        chomp @tab ;

        #it should quit foreach if mot == val 
        foreach my $val(@tab) {

          if ($mot eq $val) {

            $nb_phrase = $nb_phrase + 1;
            last;

          }

        }

    }

    print $fh_resultat "$mot:$nb_phrase\n";
}

print "$nbre_ligne\n";
```

For example if I have these 2 sentences:

```
word1 is in sentence1 word1 

word2 is in sentence2
```

the result should be:

```
word1:1

word2:1
```

Comment: `@tab` is always one element array, and `foreach/last` over it doesn't make sense.

Comment: remove the `map { split }` from the `map { split } <$fh2>;`

Comment: You have `use autodie;` twice and you don't have `use warnings;`.

Answer (score 4):

The code expects `@tab_phrase_CORPUS` to contain lines, but it contains words.

```
my @tab_phrase_CORPUS = do {
    open my $fh2, "<:utf8", CORPUS_Phrases;
    map { split } <$fh2>;
};
```

should be

```
my @tab_phrase_CORPUS = do {
    open my $fh2, "<:utf8", CORPUS_Phrases;
    map { chomp; $_ } <$fh2>;
};
```

---

Tip: Remove `chomp @tab;`. The newlines have already been removed as you read from the file, which is the proper time to do it.

Tip: `my @tab = split(/ /, $ph);` is better written as `my @tab = split(' ', $ph);`. The former splits on individual spaces, the latter is a special case that splits on whitespace.